# Why is the downloadable Might & Magic: Heroes VI demo asking for a disc?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I just downloaded the Might & Magic: Heroes VI demo from Steam.  On trying to start it, I'm receiving an error that suggests I'm missing a DVD:

> There is no disk in the drive. [Cancel] [Try Again] [Continue]

All of the buttons make the dialog disappear for a fraction of a second, and then it appears again.

Has anyone else had this problem or managed to work around it?

Comment: A clear case of the developers going "Works for *me*, let's ship it!"

Comment: Either that or Ubisoft's  latest DRM scheme being *spectacularly* crappy even by their standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, I just figured it out by going nuts on the dialog box.

Just hit Cancel 20 or 30 times - eventually it'll go away and the demo will start.  Seems like a bad sign, but we'll see.

Comment: "Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results." - Albert Einstein